# What's going on with this Fermi-gas density calculation in $D$-dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

The particle density of a Fermi-gas with $N$ particles occupying a volume $V$ is given by [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion)

$$n=\int\nu_D(\epsilon)\,f(\epsilon)\,d\epsilon \tag{1}$$

where $n$ is the particle density, $\nu_D(\epsilon)$ is the density of states in $D$-dimensions with respect to energy, and $f(\epsilon)$ is the Fermi occupation number,

$$f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)/T}+1} \tag{2}$$

In reference [1] (first page), and in most other places where I see integrals like this showing up, the technique known as [Sommerfeld expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion) is employed. For the case of integral (1) up above, this leads to, up to second-order,

$$n=\int_0^\mu \nu_D(\epsilon)\,d\epsilon+\frac{\pi^2 T^2}{6}\left.\frac{d\nu_D}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=\mu}+\mathcal{O}\,(T^4)$$

Now, a requirement of Sommerfeld expansion is that the function $\nu_D(\epsilon)$ tends to zero at $\epsilon\to\infty$. Otherwise, the integration by parts which established its validity in the first place won't work (see [this page](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermalhtml/node107.html) for the explicit details). **But the density of states $\nu_D(\epsilon)$ does not satisfy this property at all!** For an ideal Fermi-gas, the density-of-states looks like:

$$\nu_D(\epsilon)=(constant)\times\epsilon^{\frac{D}{2}-1} \tag{3}$$

What's going on here? I think I've screwed up somewhere, since I don't think it's impossible to define the chemical potential of a Fermi-gas in terms of $n$ and $T$ for $D>1$.

**References:**

[1] http://www.iiassvietri.it/TC/TCXVI/Download/Pruschke/assigment1.pdf

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion

Comment: The Fermi function exponentially decreases as $\epsilon \rightarrow \infty$ and hence it kills any power law infinities.

Comment: @Hosein You know what, I think my problem is that I'm mixing up two different definitions of the Sommerfeld expansion - one where the lower limit of integration is $0$ and one where the lower limit of integration is $-\infty$. From the point of view of integration by parts, all that seems to be needed is that the function in the integral ($\nu_D(\epsilon)$ in my case) vanishes at this lower limit of integration.

Comment: No that's not even needed. Because you write $ \int_0^{\infty} \nu(\epsilon) f(\epsilon) d\epsilon = \left{ f(\epsilon) (\int_0^{\epsilon} \v(\epsilon') d\epsilon') \right |_0 ^{\infty}- \int_0^{\infty} f'(\epsilon) (\int_0^{\epsilon} \v(\epsilon') d\epsilon') d\epsilon $ and the first term on the right hand side is zero ( for $\epsilon=0$ the integral of $\nu$ is zero and for $\epsilon=\infty$ the fermi distribution funtion is zero).

Comment: @Hosein Your comment isn't formatted properly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit it because the "edit" link is under other links in my screen and so isn't accessible.

Comment: No that's not even needed. Because you write $\int_0^{\infty} \nu(\epsilon) f(\epsilon) d\epsilon =  f(\epsilon) (\int_0^{\epsilon} \nu(\epsilon') d\epsilon')  |_0 ^{\infty}- \int_0^{\infty} f'(\epsilon) (\int_0^{\epsilon} \nu(\epsilon') d\epsilon') d\epsilon$  and the first term on the right hand side is zero ( for $\epsilon=0$ the integral of $\nu$ is zero and for $\epsilon\rightarrow \infty$ the fermi distribution funtion is zero).